# How to simply animate an UIimageView?

Tags: swift, animation

I want to move a 40, 40 pixel square from the top to the bottom, then repeat that action over a period of 3 seconds. Where would I put the entire thing in the viewcontroller? There is no start button so would I put in in the viewdidload?

So far I have this

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {

        }, completion: {

    })
```

As somewhere to start. Would I set the image to equal UIView? What should It look like? the image is called mrock.
I tried using blank.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)) in the animations part, but dont I need A UIBezierPath thing?

Comment: Please include [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @picciano stated you should have an `IBOutlet` to an `UIImageView` if you are using storyboards. So you in your view controller you can try something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //'img' is a picture imported in your project
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "img")
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let newPos: CGFloat = 300.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, newPos, CGFloat(self.imageView.bounds.size.width), CGFloat(self.imageView.bounds.size.height))
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, consider putting the animation in `viewWillAppear`, then disable it if needed in `viewDidDisappear`.

Second, if you're using auto layout, you will probably need to create an `IBOutlet` for the relevant constraint and animate the `constant` property of the constraint rather than the position of the view object directly.